# Getting data into a GSP

Tags: grails, gsp

I have a template that is rendered inside another GSP. I can't seem to find a way to populate the data into it. It is a generate show page of my students class/controller. So the student controller should process the 'show' function, however it is never getting into that function. 
  Is there a way to get the data from the student table and populate the studentInstance.id, studentInstance.Name, etc?

Additionally, are there any good books/ websites that really explain GSP. I can't find any that have really good references to the more complex actions.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find all the information you need about Controllers, GSPs and templates in the [Grails user guide](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/6.%20The%20Web%20Layer.html), more specifically in the Web Layer section.

Comment: I have been through the users guide. The page is in the correct folder to access the controller, however, there is never a call to the controller to pull the data. I have also tried loading the page outside of the embedded render call, straight from the browser, and again, there is no call to the show function in the controller.

Comment: Mark can you share some of your code? Please include how you're mapping your action in the UrlMappings.groovy

Comment: One of my classes is an account:                               class Account {
Double accountBalance
Integer accountNumber
Boolean active
 
static belongsTo = [customer: Customer]
static hasMany = [bill: Bill, payment: Payment, fee: Fees, credit: Credit]
static mappedBy = [bill: "billingAccount", payment: "paidAccount", fee: "chargedAccount", credit: "creditedAccount"]
 
static constraints = {accountNumber(nullable: true)
accountBalance(nullable: true)
bill(nullable: true)
credit(nullable: true)
fee(nullable: true)}
String toString(){return accountNumber}}

Comment: The URLMapping is:                                          "/account/_showAccount.gsp"{
controller="account" action="show"}                                                      The _showAccount.gsp right now is just a generate-views version of the show page that gets generated. So I have not do anything to really change the linkage to the show function in the controller. It is located in the /account directory of the views.

Comment: The account controller show is the default generated:                                                             def show = {
   def accountInstance = Account.get(params.id)
   println "SHOW Params: ${params}" <<This never show an output
if (!accountInstance) {flash.message = "${message(code: 'default.not.found.message', args: [message(code: 'account.label', default: 'Account'), params.id])}"
redirect(action: "list")}
  else {[accountInstance: accountInstance]}
}

Comment: I'm sorry if this seems to be a newbee question, but it just doesn't seem to work the way it should, and I can't find anything that explains how to forcibly get data into the GSP.  Thanks for any help you can provide.

Comment: Mark it seems to me that the Urlmapping you are using needs to be different and for what you need you can use the default one that Grails provide /$controller/$action/$id?, in this way you can call /action/show/1, this will call the action show of the Account controller. Then the action in the controller would look for a view file named show.gsp under /views/account/ unless you specify a different view, which you can do by doing render(view: "someOtherView", model: [accountInstance: accountInstance]). You specify a different view you would need to have a file named someOtherView.gsp.

Comment: If you want to return a template from an action you need to specify it like render(template: "someTemplate", model:[accountInstance: accountInstance]) and for the template the file should be named as _someTemplate.gsp. Hope this helps!

Comment: Maricel - Thanks so much, you pointed me in the exact spot. I know it must be something simple, I just couldn't for the life of me figure out what it was. You second set of eyes got it. Again thanks. BTW - my post looks like crap, how do you inject the code without exceeding the character limit?

Comment: I am glad you were able to fix it. About the code, the amount of characters in the comments section is limited, you would need to edit the actual question to add the code there and format it.

Answer (score 0):

To pass data into a template, use the `model` parameter.  Here's an example I grabbed out of some of my code:

```
<g:render template="/voteAndScore" model="['wysiap': wysiap, 'showVote': false, 'showDiscuss': true, 'updatedWysiaps': updatedWysiaps]" />
```

As for documentation, pretty much everything is available [here](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/6.%20The%20Web%20Layer.html#6.2%20Groovy%20Server%20Pages).  But I've found Grails in Action to be a helpful read in addition.

Comment: Kaleb, thanks for the post, I was doing the render, but dynamically, and the data wasn't getting pulled. It is working now.